# Django social_django query to table

Tags: django, django-models

It is necessary to receive a line from the table `social_auth_usersocialauth` which is in the database. The table was created by `social_django`.

Tried `from social_django.models import social_auth_usersocialauth` but so does not find the table.

How do I refer to the table `social_auth_usersocialauth`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from social_django.models import UserSocialAuth
```